# Sql count query from different value on same column

Tags: sql, select, count

I have table that look like this called `new_attendance`

```
Student_id | Attendance | Date       | Class     |Subject
-----------------------------------------------
2010639201 | No         |  1/10/2014 | Lecture   | CSC435
2010639202 | Yes        |  3/10/2014 | Tutorial  | CSC240
2010639203 | Yes        | 10/10/2014 | Tutorial  | CSP650
2010639201 | No         |  2/10/2014 | Lab       | CSC520
2010639201 | No         |  4/10/2014 | Tutorial  | ITT545
2010639204 | No         |  5/10/2014 | Tutorial  | CSP600
2010639205 | No         |  6/10/2014 | Tutorial  |ITT550
2010639206 | No         |  7/10/2014 | Lab       | CSC520
```

How can I write a SQL count query to count the number of absent (Attendance="No") with the number of class?

Expected output:

```
Student_id|No of absent|% of Absent|
------------------------------------
2010639202|3|3.57%
```

Formula:

```
% of absent= ((no absent* (Lab+ Tutorial+ Lecture) ) / (14* subject_contachour) *100
```

Comment: Could you please provide expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like here is what you looking for:

```
SELECT `Class`, count(*)
FROM `new_attendance`
WHERE `Attendance` = 'No'
GROUP BY `Class`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
CREATE TABLE new_attendance (student_id INT(11), attendance binary,
class VARCHAR(20), att_date DATE);

INSERT INTO `new_attendance` (`student_id`, `attendance`, `class`, `att_date`) VALUES
(2323,1,'CCNA','2013-09-12'), 
(453,0,'CCNA','2013-09-12'), 
(2435,1,'PHP','2013-09-12'), 
(324,0,'PHP','2013-09-12'), 
(2546,1,'CCNA','2013-09-12'), 
(897,0,'PHP','2013-09-12') 

SELECT `class`, count(*) AS total
FROM `new_attendance`
WHERE `attendance` = 0
GROUP BY `class`
```

result is like this

```
Class                 total
CCNA                    1
PHP                     2
```

Comment: every subject should have lecture,lab and tutorial. how to code the query as lecture=2hours, lab=2hours and tutorial=1hour?

Comment: @user3838126 it means your table has lecture,lab, and tutorial columns that type of all of them is time?

Comment: @user3830126 do you want the query result should take absent student and number of class of only one tutorial and two lecture and two labs?

Comment: yes.in my table have lecture, lab and tutorial.Then i need to calculate total hour student did not attend based on lecture, lab and tutorial for certain subject.The formula like this:  % of absent= (total hour student absent to class)/(14*subjectcontacthour)*100

Comment: For example one student did not attend for one subject like CSC435 and  they did not attend for 2 days. 2 days maybe lecture and tutorial of CSC435. How it can be solved?